# AzureResourceManager template hook Azure Function to Storage Event

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

I've got an AzureResourceManager template that's creating both a StorageAccount, as well as AzureFunctions.  I want to add a JSON node to subscribe the functions to the Blob storage events.  This URL explains how:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-subscription-template

But I'm not sure how to populate the "endpointURL", as this function is not static, but rather generated earlier in the template.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/eventSubscriptions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/myStorageSubscription')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
            "properties": {
                "destination": {
                    "endpointType": "WebHook",
                    "properties": {
                        "endpointUrl": "<WHAT GOES HERE?>"
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "subjectBeginsWith": "",
                    "subjectEndsWith": "",
                    "isSubjectCaseSensitive": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: create a function using the portal with the property you need and analyze what goes in there.

Comment: I don't think that helps me here, as I need reference to dynamic information created earlier in my template?  ie,
1) Create Azure Function App (which, after completion, should have a URL and key I can use to invoke the function)
2) Create event grid subscription using URL/key generated in #1

Comment: well, if you dont understand what to generate dynamically you are not able to generate it